# parse first 2 characters of string and then vlookup to return answer

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a giant excel workbook of printers, with each separate floor having its own sheet, that my office uses to manage maintenance. I compiled all the printers onto a single sheet that I am referencing from. The first column contains printer names, the middle column displays the printer status, and the third column is where I will eventually display the repair part needed or any comments. I am using this sub to determine to which sheet I need to do my VLookup reference.

Problem 1:
I need to reference "A3:A82" from the new sheet I compiled and not just "A3". Is there a better way for me to do my 3rd line of code?

Problem 2: 
Where my IF statements currently return MsgBoxs, I eventually want them to utilize VLookups to reference the respective floor's sheet and display the 3 cells to the right of the printer name. Is the best approach to use offsets?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Sub FindFloor()  

Dim PrinterName As Long  
the_value = Sheets("magic").Range("A3")

    If Mid(the_value, 5, 2) = 11 Then
        MsgBox "11th floor"
    End If

    If Mid(the_value, 5, 2) = 12 Then
        MsgBox "12th floor"
    End If

    If Mid(the_value, 5, 2) = 14 Then
        MsgBox "14th floor"
    End If

    If Mid(the_value, 5, 2) = 15 Then
        MsgBox "15th floor"
    End If

    If Mid(the_value, 5, 2) = 16 Then
        MsgBox "16th floor"
    End If

    If Mid(the_value, 5, 2) = 17 Then
        MsgBox "17th floor"
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Problem 1: I need to reference "A3:A82" from the new sheet I compiled and not just "A3". Is there a better way for me to do my 3rd line of code?

Sure. You need to do this in a loop.  Also modified it to make a more efficient function to return the floor name like "11th floor", etc.

```
Sub FindFloor()  
Dim myRange as Range
Dim values as Variant
Dim the_value as Variant
Dim floorName as String
Dim PrinterName As Long  
values = Application.Transponse(Sheets("magic").Range("A3:A82"))

For each the_value in values
    Select Case Mid(the_value, 5, 2)
        Case 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17
            floorName = Mid(the_value, 5, 2) & "th floor"

        Case Else
        ' you didn't specify anything to do with other 
        ' results, so this does nothing
    End Select
    MsgBox the_value & " --> " & floorName
Next
End Sub
```

For part 2, I might need more information. Is the resulting messagebox the sheet name (e.g., "11th floor")?  Over what range in that sheet will you be searching with VLOOKUP/etc.?

Assuming you're looking for `the_value` in column A, and would like to return the corresponding data in column C, you could do something like this:

```
Dim returnedValue as Variant
returnedValue = Application.Vlookup(the_value, Sheets(floorName).Range("A1:C100"), 3, False)

If IsError(returnedValue) Then MsgBox the_value & " not found!"
```

Comment: ![11th floor printers](http://imgur.com/jlSuTeG).
![compiled printer list](http://imgur.com/PcJTn8p).

I was having a hard time communicating the situation so I took two quick screenshots. 

I want to use this sub to find the appropriate sheet to go to. After going to that sheet, I want to take the values from the  4 cells to the right of the printer name (assuming they are not blank or an "x") and somehow display them to the user - ie. a messagebox now anyways for testing purposes.

I'm having a hard time clarifying. Do you have a better understanding of what I am trying to do now?

Comment: you want to display the value from the Magenta column (4 cells to the right of printer name) or the Notes column which is 5 to the right?

Comment: I want to display all four of the column values to the right of the printer name (black, cyan, yellow, and magenta) so long as the value is not equal to "" or "x". Sorry about that, my initial wording was confusing now that I look back.

Comment: OK, so the example I gave you does one VLOOKUP and returns the information from column 5. You need to do 4 VLOOKUPs which would be structured nearly identically -- only the third argument will differ, as 1, 2, 3, 4 (instead of `5` as in my answer).  There are several other methods you could use to do this, but here we are already like 95% of the way there and it will be best if you can try to adapt the solution already provided.  Can you give it a shot?  You can revise your Q with your updated code if you get stuck, and I can try to help.